# Bug: Favorites sort order and page not persisted on browser back

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, bookmarks, navigation

Steps to reproduce:

> 1. Go to favorites page.
> 2. Change the sort order or view a different page of favorites.
> 3. Click through to a question.
> 4. Press browser's back button.
> 5. *Sort order reverts to "votes" and it shows page 1, no matter where you were.*

Expected behavior:

> Sort order is persisted and it shows the same page you were on before you clicked through. That is, the back button takes you back to exactly what you saw before and doesn't reset the view.

Anyone else notice this?

Comment: I had a very similar observation. Feel free to merge them if you like. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8626/make-sort-order-for-questions-and-answers-on-user-pages-sticky

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hear hear.

It's worth noting that this isn't just related to the back button. If you go into your profile, select favorites, sort by newest, then quick questions, then profile / favorites again, it will have been reverted to votes again.

Just because it's related to it being an AJAX call doesn't mean it's not a bug, IMO. It's defying the user's expectations (partially set by sort order elsewhere being sticky). It may be harder to work around due to being an AJAX call, but it can't be impossible... the AJAX call *could* set a flag in the user profile, for instance - and that flag come down to the page when the user fetches the list of favorites next time.

I suppose it could count as "not a bug" in terms of working as designed, but in that case I'd say the feature is not as well designed as it might be :)

(I don't mean to sound whiny in all of this... it's not like I don't appreciate all the cool stuff the team does :)

Answer (score 0):

not a bug, as this is an AJAX call and not an URL in the browser.

Comment: I think, consider it as a feature request.

Comment: now that you've implemented this, any chance the users search page could get the same treatment?