# Make sort order for questions and answers on user pages sticky

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, sorting, navigation

Currently Questions and Answers listings under the stats tab on the user page can be sorted by Recent, Views, Newest and Votes. By default the sort order is by votes. If you select a different sort order then refresh the page the sort order is reset to votes. It'd be nice if the sort order was remembered across page visits.

Comment: Possible dupe - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3458/bug-favorites-sort-order-and-page-not-persisted-on-browser-back

Comment: @ChrisF, extremely similar. It's speaking about favorites so no wonder it didn't come up in my search.

Comment: "status-completed" Thank you Jeff. I'm enjoying this feature already. :)